# Exporting email address of all users in Security Group

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to script something where I can get the email address of all users in an active directory security group.

What I have so far:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like "VIPEmail" } | Select-Object Name
ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
  Get-ADGroupMember -identity $($group.name) -recursive | Select-Object samaccountname
}
```

Obviously this will only return the samaccountname, which it does.  I replace samaccountname with EmailAddress, and it does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep with your original formatting so you can see where you went wrong:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like "09-Admins" } | Select-Object Name
ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
   Get-ADGroupMember -identity $($group.name) -recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties mail | Select-Object mail
}
```

The problem is that you are trying to read a property that the Get-ADGroupMember return type doesn't have (Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPrincipal). You need to pipe that return into Get-ADuser AND specify that you want it to pull the emailaddress property. Get-ADUser will not pull most properties of a user by default, so you need to specify any additional properties you would like to retrieve (or just select all of them with "-Properties *", but that's kind of sloppy).

Mjolinor beat me to the answer, but I figured it was worth elaborating a little on his response.

Comment: I like this answer better :) 

One thing though if you can assist.  What I'm trying to do is migrate all of the users in the group VIPEmail to another exchange database.  How do I use the results "mail" with my move command?

Comment: I haven't done a huge amount of work in the Exchange Shell, but I found an article that may help. [link](http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/moving-mailboxes-exchange-2010-part1.html)

It looks like New-MoveRequest just needs an -Identity parameter to determine what it targets, which gives you quite a bit of leeway on how you target the request.

Comment: Yeah, I know how to move the mailbox using New-MoveRequest -Identity $emailaddress -TargetDatabase "DB01", my issues is assigning the variable $emailaddress with the email addresses that i'm pulling from the group VIPEmail. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:'

```
Get-ADGroup -filter {name -like 'VIPEmail'} | 
Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive |
Get-ADUser -Properties Mail |
select -ExpandProperty Mail
```

Comment: thanks that works.  One issue, i'm getting an error "select : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "obj" is null", anyways to keep going if the value mail is null?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add unique. So when a user is in more groups only one email is shown:

```
Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like "RO*" } | 
Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive | 
select -Unique| 
get-adUser -Properties mail |
select -ExpandProperty Mail
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADGroupMember GroupName | get-aduser -properties mail | select mail | Sort-Object mail
```

If you have groups nested you can change the above to:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Recursive GroupName | get-aduser -properties mail | select mail | Sort-Object mail
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity your_ad_group_name_here -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties *  | Select SamAccountName,mail,EmailAddress,Manager
```

...just make sure you've installed the necessary powershell module so you have access to `Get-ADGroupMember`. You can download the `WindowsTH-RSAT_WS_*` specific to your version of Windows 10 here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520.